# Why is this equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vectors, inner-products

I came across this in a reading:
$2\vec{x}'' \cdot \vec{x} =0$ $\implies$ $\vec{x}'' \cdot \vec{x}' = 0.$

How can you just drop the constant?

Comment: multiply the first equation by $\frac{1}{2}$. Also, in the second implication did you mean $\vec{x}''\cdot \vec{x}=0$?

Comment: no I wrote it correctly @peek-a-boo

Comment: How can you multiply by $1/2$ without affecting the $\vec{x}'$?

Comment: @Derik: Without context, if $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{x}'$ are different vectors, then there's no reason for the first equation to have anything to do with the second. If they're the same vector (due to typographic error in your book or in your transcription), then the implication follows from the fact that $(k\vec{u})\cdot(\vec{v})=k\,(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})$.

Comment: What peek-a-boo & Blue said. It would be good to have more context. Eg, is $ \vec{x}=\vec{x}'=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the notation $\langle x,y \rangle$ instead of $x\cdot y$ as I think it becomes more clear then. I would assume there either is a typographic error in your book, or there is information you have not given us, because what you wrote does not seem correct, and I will explain why.

In general, if you have a real (but complex works just as well) inner product space $V$, then the inner product, by definition, satisfies linearity in the first argument. In your case this means that if $x,y\in V$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, then

$$\langle \lambda x,y\rangle = \lambda \langle x,y\rangle.$$

In your case I am guessing that your inner product space is $\mathbb{R}^n$, and that you have $\vec{x} : \mathbb{R}\supset\kern-1.7pt\to \mathbb{R}^n$. Then also $\vec{x}',\vec{x}'':\mathbb{R}\supset\kern-1.7pt\to \mathbb{R}^n$, and so you would have that for any $t\in \operatorname{dom}(\vec{x})\cap\operatorname{dom}(\vec{x}''),$

$$\langle 2 \vec{x}''(t),\vec{x}(t)\rangle=2\langle \vec{x}''(t),\vec{x}(t)\rangle,$$

and so what you book most likely is intended to say is that

$$\langle 2 \vec{x}''(t),\vec{x}(t)\rangle=0 \implies \langle \vec{x}''(t),\vec{x}(t)\rangle=0.$$

However if we look at what it is currently saying then I can give a counterexample to why it does not hold in general. I will assume we are dealing with the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the scalar product given by the relation

$$\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{j=1}^n x_jy_j.$$

Let us specifically consider the function

$$\vec{x} : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2, \quad t\mapsto (t^2-2t,t^2).$$

Then $\vec{x}'$ and $\vec{x}''$ are given by

$$\vec{x}'(t)=2(t-1,t), \quad \vec{x}''(t)=(2,2).$$

We have that

$$\langle 2\vec{x}''(1),\vec{x}(1)\rangle=\langle (4,4), (-1,1)\rangle=-4+4=0,$$

but also

$$\langle \vec{x}''(1),\vec{x}'(1)\rangle=\langle (4,4), (0,2)\rangle=4.$$

So even though $\langle 2\vec{x}''(1),\vec{x}(1)\rangle$ is zero, we do not have that $\langle \vec{x}''(1),\vec{x}'(1)\rangle$ is zero. And this is why I believe there is simply a typographic error in your book.